# Unsure why fraction is not compiling

Tags: math-mode, fractions, parentheses

I have a piece of text like:

```
They use a metric similar to my cost metric which is more lenient than
traditional population evaluation metrics, which is 
$$sim(x,g) = max\paren{1−\frac{\abs{x-g}}{\abs{g}},0}$$
```

However this is not compiling. What is going wrong?

Relevant packages and redefinitions:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}% This is for maths. Note, fleqn makes it left aligned. [fleqn]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
% note: \lvert and \rvert look like | and |, but are spaced as
% delimiters,so they'll look a little nicer
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
```

The equation should look like: https://cl.ly/0l0g3B1r3E44

Comment: complete MWE please.

Comment: If you have copied it from somewhere you have some invisible nonASCII characters in the expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiled fine for me, but you used some symbol that resembled a minus sign instead of the minus sign itself in your math equation, which resulted in the minus sign being dropped.  Further, don't use `$$ ... $$`, the ams packages are loaded by `mathtools`, use upright (roman) for `words' in your math, and adjust bracket sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% This is for maths. Note, fleqn makes it left aligned. [fleqn]
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
% note: \lvert and \rvert look like | and |, but are spaced as
% delimiters,so they'll look a little nicer
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
%\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\simo}{sim}

\begin{document}
They use a metric similar to my cost metric which is more lenient than traditional population evaluation metrics, which is 
\begin{equation}
 \simo(x,g) = \max\paren[\bigg]{1-\frac{\abs{x-g}}{\abs{g}},0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to read "don't use `$$ ... $$`", instead of "don't use $$" - I thought the original was easy to misunderstand as "don't use `$ ... $`" and while that may not be the LaTeX way, it tends not to be deprecated in quite the same way as `$$ ... $$`. If you meant don't use `$` at all for entering math mode, then obviously feel free to change it back and sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: No, your edit improved my answer.